# How to view all xpad sticky notes

Tags: stickynotes

I just installed Xpad and I can only see the last sticky note saved.
Where can I found all the rest I saved?

Answer (score 2):

Just right click on the one you can see and choose `Notes->show all` and all your notes will be displayed on the screen.

See screenshot below:

[image]

The result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Also, Xpad v4.2 (https://launchpad.net/xpad) offers a new functionality when clicking on the systray icon. It can be configured to show/hide all the notes at once.

Does this help you?

Answer (score 0):

You also need to "open all pads":

[image]